# Integrated ecommerce and forum software applications

Tags: forum, ecommerce

Would anyone be aware of integrated open source software that does ecommerce and forum functions in one package?
Alternatively, could there be some way to integrate two separate packages so that they use a common authentication system?

Answer (score 1):

[Odoo](https://www.odoo.com/) might be your answer. It is a full featured e-commerce system with many plugins. It is open source and Bitnami has installers for it.